# Security measures for mobile (android) application to be deployed on google play store

Tags: java, android, spring-boot, ssl, oauth-2.0

Please inform what security measures need to be implemented before I can deploy an android app (which will collect personal information) for public usage in google play store. I am a newbie and dont have much experience with security procedures.

1. Already implemented SSL to establish encrypted secure data link between client and server by converting http to https. Is this good enough for data communication between client and server link?
2. Will be implementing sending email from app securely using OAuth2. Is this a valid approach? Should more be done. I plan to write this code at the server side and not from the client side? Is this ok?

3) I just do a simple retrieval of username and password and check if they match but password retrieval is done using https (SSL). Is this enough?

4) Should I encrypt the passwords in the database? If yes, how should it be done like should I store them encrypted in the database and which retrieval decrypt them? Please inform.

5) Will be composing a privacy policy as per guidelines of google play as the app will be requesting personal information and displaying on the app menu and while first sign up before entering the app?

6) Also using google API's etc...Just requesting, getting JSON, parsing the json and displaying in the app good enough or something needs to be done. This is all done using api key as per the provided guidelines. Anything more needs to be done to secure it?

7) What else am I missing to make the app absolutely secure?

Your inputs will be greatly helpful.

Thank you!!!

Comment: Props for thinking about thinks like these, but this question is simply too broad for Stack Overflow. You should checkout the OWASP's [Authentication Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Authentication_Cheat_Sheet). (You should never store a password in a way that is recoverable. Including by decrypting it. And **definitely** don't send it to back to verify it on the user's device.) (Also "absolutely secure" is a myth.)

Comment: Yes...it seems like a whole area I need to familiarize with but the info with the password was really useful.